# unable to find an inherited method for function 'saveXML' for signature '"XMLDocument"'

Tags: r, xml, xpath

Can anywone tell me why this code:

```
filename3 = "restaurants.xml"
if (!file.exists(filename3)) csv <- download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml", filename3, "curl")
if (!exists("data3")) data3 <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(filename3, useInternalNodes = TRUE))
zips <- xpathSApply(data3, "//zipcode", xmlValue)
```

is giving me the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'saveXML' for signature '"XMLDocument"'
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce that using  "R version 3.3.0 Patched (2016-05-03 r70575)" and XML ‘3.98.1.4’ on Windows.  For me `zips` is produced witih no error.

Comment: Works for me, too (R version 3.3.0, x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), XML_3.98-1.3). And I' wondering where `saveXML` comes into play there. Maybe some code block is missing?

Comment: My function is a bit of a Frankenstein function and I did trim out some of what I thought was completely unrelated code. There is obviously some interaction there that I'm not seeing. @lukeA, you made me go back, clear my workspace and run only what I posted, and it works fine. I checked it before I posted it, but I didn't clear the workspace first. So I've learned a new trick. Thanks to both of you for your help.